# Why does releasing a pressed "f" key not prevent the coroutine from spinning?

Tags: unity

I am learning Unity and the following is my simplification of the code presented on [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/510/Documentation/Manual/Coroutines.html).

My expectation is that the `Fade()` just spins in a very very short period of time because the `GetKeyDown("f")` is `true` only at the transition from "unpressed" to "pressed" states.

However in the following code, the `Fade()` spins from `f=0` to `f=999` continuously (non stop in one go) rather than for example, from `f=0` to `f=100` at the first key press and from `f=101`
to `f=159` at the second key press, etc.

```
IEnumerator Fade()
{
    for (int f = 0; f < 1000; f++)
    {            
        Debug.Log($"{f}");
        yield return null;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("f"))
    {
        StartCoroutine("Fade");
    }
}
```

## Question

What causes this unexpected result and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StartCoroutine` does exactly that: it *starts* the coroutine. The coroutine then continues running independently of the code that started it ([when its turn comes in the engine's single-threaded script update loop](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html), not in parallel), until you tell it to stop.

You can stop it from an outside method, the same way you started it, by holding a reference to the running coroutine:

```
Coroutine myFade;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("f"))
    {   // Start the coroutine when the F key transitions from up to down.
        myFade = StartCoroutine(Fade());
    }
    // The coroutine will continue running since we don't tell it otherwise.
    if (Input.GetKeyUp("f")) 
    {   // Stop the coroutine when the F key transitions from down to up.
        StopCoroutine(myFade);
        myFade = null;
    }
}
```

Or you could make the coroutine check for its own stopping condition:

```
IEnumerator Fade()
{
    for (int f = 0; f < 1000; f++)
    {   
        if(Input.GetKeyUp("f"))
            yield break;

        Debug.Log($"{f}");
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

It sounds like what you're expecting rather than `StartCoroutine()` is something like a "`StepCoroutine()`" method, where the coroutine advances only when you ask it to in Update. You can manage something similar with your original `IEnumerator` like so:

```
IEnumerator myFade;

void Update() {
    // When we strike the key, start the enumeration if we didn't already.
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("f") && myFade == null)
        myFade = Fade();

    // As long as the key is held, step the enumeration.
    if (Input.GetKey("f")) 
        myFade.MoveNext();
}
```

Here because we're managing the frames when we want to run the enumerator's code ourselves, we don't need to wrap it in a Unity coroutine for the engine to manage its lifetime and keep stepping it without us.

Though we could simplify this example further to just:

```
int iterationCount = 0;
void Update() {
    if(Input.GetKey("f") && iterationCount < 1000)
        Debug.Log(iterationCount++);
}
```

With no `IEnumerator` at all.

Comment: I think the result is a bit different from my expectation. Repressing should continue the counter rather than starting from zero again. Thank you!

Comment: Then don't create a new instance each time the key as pressed, as shown in the edit above, in the last code example.